Search through lookup file in abinitio
I have a large file 300 million+ records. it has landline numbers details.
I have another file with codes and their district name.
Need to get district name from codes file by searching codes(length may vary for each record) which are part of landline numbers and get district name.
Input:
011234234234
044234234233
042223423432
03698987763
036989898989
+03634234234
Codes:
011,aaa
044,bbb
0412,ccc
0422,ddd
037,eee
036,fff
Output
011234234234,aaa
044234234233,bbb
042223423432,ddd
03698987763,eee
036989898989,eee
+03634234234,eee
I tried using statments in abinitio reformat. loaded entire codes file as vector into a vector variable. then using for loop i traversed through vector and used string_like function and take matching state. Its working but taking lot of time(going through 900 lines for each record in input). any way to achieve this requirement in efficient way
